# undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM' in voce.h

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to make a program that can detect speech so I downloaded voce to help with it. After I have included all packages I get the error `undefined reference to 'JNI_CreateJavaVM'`. I searched on it and and I found no solution that worked.

I use Code::Blocks IDE and GNU GCC as compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have not compiled it using the required linker information.

To do this after the other compiler options you need to add something like :

```
gcc -o myapp -I<path-to-jni-include-files> myapp.c -L <path-to-libjvm.so> -ljvm
```

The -L tells the *linker* ( the compiler passes these options to the linker for you ) where to find the shared libraries it needs, and the -ljvm tells the linker to actually expect references the libjvm.so shared library ( as it would be called on Linux ).

Note that current gcc versions require the linker options at the end of the command line.  Once upon a time you could place them in any order you like.  Now they must be at the end.